# Jaeger tracing with stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, trace, stackdriver, zipkin, jaeger

I am hosting my application on GCP and I want to use stackdriver as my backend storage for trace spans with jaeger collectors. I can't seem to find anything related to that.

In GCP I can find clearly that they support zipkin. I am not sure what to do here. Should I create some translation layer to push the data to stackdriver ? Or is it supported somehow by the current zipkin connector ?

I truly wouldn't want to host my full tracing solution to avoid having to maintain it. Can I run the Jaeger collector and somehow pass it to stackdriver ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I don't need neither Zipkin nor Jaeger to have my traces on Stackdriver. All that is needed is a deployment of [zipkin-collector](http://gcr.io/stackdriver-trace-docker/zipkin-collector) and a service to point to it and all my traces are now reporting as expected on GCP Stackdriver.